# reading specific characters from a text file in java

Tags: java, file, input

Before I posted the question, I was searching on the idea, but almost of the answers are not clear for me.

Here is my question: If i have a file contain that contains following string :

```
45BBHBBBH STREWR GGTEREWEF FRERREWEFFSF FS  W WEERER TWR WR
```

How can I read this string character by character ?

I want the first to string be stored in variable on variable and the next in another example:

```
A = 4 

B = 5
```

After that, I want read the rest of string with some logic.

I want to split it into 6 strings and store them in some form data structure

```
BBHBBB > index 0

BH STR > index 1 ( with the space )
```

and so on

Comment: You can use String.charAt(n) to get individual characters and String.substring(start, end) to get a sub string.

Comment: read the file line by line, everyline is a string, make a for loop to get every char of the string

Comment: `"45BBHBBBH...".toCharArray()` isn't good enough?

Answer (score 0):

use a char[] to store all the values but instead of A= 4 it would be

```
yourCharArray[0] =4;
```

if you want to split the string at the spaces do a loop (str being your string)

```
while(str.indexOf(" ") != -1)
{
 // substring the code out individually using str.indexOf(" ");
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: `for (String s : str.split(" "))` would probably be better

Comment: keep in mind in the while loop you will need to store the "subStringed" out String into its own String before the loop ends

Comment: I tend to stay away from for each loops when answering questions just because some people may not know it :) but your right that would be best  cricket

Comment: Use a regular for loop, then. My point was that you are steering them towards an infinite loop with your sample code

Comment: while a regular loop might work it wont be able to always work with any amount of spaces

Comment: What do you mean? If you read a whole line, then spaces are included in the `length()` calculation unless you `trim()` the string as well

Comment: I agree that spaces are included in the

Comment: Length() i just meant the index of the spaces are unknown